# How many public keys with the length of 64 characters (in the range 0-9 or A-F) can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Assume a public-key cryptography system with the length of **64** characters (in the range `0-9` and `a-f` in hexadecimal).
Below is an example of a public key:

```
6d28cf8e17e4682fbe6285e72b21aa26f094d8dbd18f7828358f822b428d069f
```

How many of such keys can be formed?

While I think that the correct answer is $16^{64} = 1.15792089×10^{77}$, based on the **Permutation** formula, the answer would be different: $\frac{64!}{(64-16)!} = 1.02213465×10^{28}$.

Does this mean that the total number of possible keys with 16 letters and with the length of 64 cannot be considered **a kind of permutation**?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Personally, I dislike calling anything a permutation which does not explicitly use *each and every* option *exactly once* a piece.  In algebra, permutations are very strictly defined objects.  Unfortunately, the word has been used incorrectly in colloquial language as a generic synonym for "arrangements" without any regard to the specificity of what types of arrangements are considered.

Comment: I would instead call these *arrangements* of $k$ objects, where there are $n$ options of objects available.  Here, $n^k$ different arrangements of $k$ objects with $n$ options available where order is relevant, repetition is allowed... and using [notation from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) $n\frac{k}{~}$ or as you wrote it $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ arrangements of $k$ objects with $n$ options available where order is relevant, repetition is not allowed.  Note here that if you used the right values of $n$ and $k$ you'd have $16\frac{64}{~}=0$

Comment: Note also, that $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ gives weird results for when $k>n$ rather than the correct result of $0$ which is why this is usually not how the identity is *defined* but rather it is just a special case simplification of the identity for when $0\leq k\leq n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

The [permutation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n) $$P(n, k) = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$$ only applies when the elements in the permutation are all distinct. It is used to count arrangements (ordered selections) of $k$ elements selected from a set with $n$ elements.  We use it for problems such as finding the number of ways of selecting a president, secretary, and treasurer from a mathematics club if no person can hold more than one office.  There are $$P(20, 3) = \frac{20!}{(20 - 3)!} = \frac{20!}{17!} = \frac{20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot 17!}{17!} = 20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18$$
such selections since there are $20$ ways of selecting the president, $19$ ways of selecting the secretary from among the remaining members of the club, and $18$ ways of selecting the treasurer from among the remaining members of the club.

Strictly speaking, the elements in a permutation must be distinct.  That said, the problem you solved is sometimes called a [permutation with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition), meaning ordered arrangements of $k$ elements selected from a set elements when repetition is permitted.  The number of such strings is $n^k$ since there are $n$ possible choices for each of the $k$ positions in the string.  In your case, $n = 16$ since there are $16$ available characters and $k = 64$ since the string has length $64$, giving $16^{64}$ possible public keys.